# How do I left align components in GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

[image]

Each row in the above pic, is custom component that uses gridbaglayout for laying components.
I am trying to avoid that space before the button "Abc", I want it completely pushed to the left hand side. How do I achieve this using gridbaglayout constraints?

**EDIT** Adding Source code.

```
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gridBagConstraints.insets =  new Insets(11,0,0,0);
        add(abcButton,gridBagConstraints);
            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(20, 10, 0, 0);
        add(comp1,gridBagConstraints);
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(20, 35, 0, 0);
        add(comp2, gridBagConstraints);
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 120;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(11,20, 0, 0);
        add(txtField1, gridBagConstraints);
    btnTxtField1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 1, 2, 1));
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(11, 0, 0, 0);
        add(btnTxtField1, gridBagConstraints);
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 5;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 120;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 3;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(11, 0, 0, 0);
    add(txtField2, gridBagConstraints);
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 6;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(11, 0, 0, 0);
    add(btnTxtField2, gridBagConstraints);
```

After adding weights:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set an anchor to GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST or something like this....

```
constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

Comment: @Jay Ok. Can you post your source? Sometimes there is some "weird" behavior of other constraints...

Comment: I don't think I need to specify any weights, if the window in which this component will be used is not resizeable?

Comment: Adding this aligns the button left: `gridBagConstraints.weightx=1`

Comment: Ok. I think I have an update. I tried, constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST and constraints.gridx=1.0d. That worked, and abc button moved completely to the left, BUT, it now leaves a huge gap to the right before the next box/label. I want this box/label to move to the left as well. Ideally, I want the space to remain as it is now between components, but all of them should push left.

Comment: I think then you have to add your solution to all the other components as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13659/discussion-between-jay-and-matcauthon)